# When trying to predict if an event will happen in the next $n$ time-steps, is it a bad idea to label backwards in time?

Tags: time-series, classification, predictive-models, supervised-learning, labeling

Apologies if the title makes no sense.

At work, I came across something that I don’t think is a good idea and I was hoping someone could help me convince my colleagues of that - or convince me that I’m mistaken.

We are trying to predict if an event will happen within a given time horizon. For simplicity, let’s just say we have monthly historical data and we want to predict if an event will happen in the next 6 months. The event is always the same, so we can frame it as a supervised classification problem with only two classes: 0 and 1; 0 if the event does not happen and 1 if it does.

Here is where it becomes funny. Since we want to predict multiple steps into the future, without actually having to make multiple predictions, the dataset is labelled backwards into the past. Here is a mock-up of the dataset:

| date | feature_1 | ... | feature_n | label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | ... | ... | ... | 0 |
| 2023-02-01 | ... | ... | ... | 0 |
| 2023-03-01 | ... | ... | ... | 1 |
| 2023-04-01 | ... | ... | ... | 1 |
| 2023-05-01 | ... | ... | ... | 1 |
| 2023-06-01 | ... | ... | ... | 1 |
| 2023-07-01 | ... | ... | ... | 1 |
| 2023-08-01 | ... | ... | ... | 1 |
| 2023-09-01 | ... | ... | ... | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2023-12-01 | ... | ... | ... | 0 |

In the table above, the event happened in August 2023 (2023-08-01), and so the label is 1, but because of the chosen horizon, the label in the previous 5 months has also been given the value 1, even though the event actually didn’t happen in those.

**I don’t think this is a good idea. Am I or right or wrong, and why?**.

Intuitively, the label makes somewhat sense. It does indeed indicate that the event happened this month or one of the following 5 months.

However, my issue with it is that we are basically using data from the future in any given month. Is it a textbook example of data leakage or what’s different here? My colleagues recognise that the the labels for the past 5 months would change if the event happens next month, i.e. January 2024. The way they get around this issue if to just delete all data from the past 6 months before training the model. If the horizon is longer, you can guess what happens.. (and I still don’t think that solves much).

Comment: Wikipedia has a pretty good definition of leakage: "leakage is the use of information in the model training process which would not be expected to be available at prediction time". However, I would add that this does not apply to the target column ("label" here)--it will never be available at prediction time. In order to be leakage, it needs to come from feature columns. I see nothing inherently wrong with the way the target column is formed.

Comment: @jblood94 Thanks! I went straight to wikipedia. It also mentions “row-wise leakage” which is “is caused by improper sharing of information between rows of data.” I wonder what would happen if I split the data into train and test datasets at 2023-05-01 letting everything on or before that be the training set. The label is 1 (because the event happens in August), but August is in the test set... Not exactly a duplicate row between train/test, but kinda?

Comment: That is easily addressed by configuring a gap between the training and the validation sets for each series. In this case, you would set the gap to 6 months. E.g., train up through 2020-12-01 and then validate starting at 2021-06-01.

Answer (score 2):

If understand correctly, the column "label" is your target variable, that is, the correct prediction that you want to train your algorithm to make. You're training the algorithm to predict, at a a particular point in time, if the event will occur in the next 6 months. For any time 6 months prior to an event, the algorithm should indeed be predicting a 1, as that is the truly correct response. You should not train the algorithm to predict a 0 at that time, as that's the wrong answer.

I don't think this is an example of data leakage, that typically occurs when the features you are using to predict are in practice unavailable or themselves contain the feature you're trying to predict. Here, the "label" column is used to evaluate your training, but it should not be used as an input feature itself, since that's exactly what you're trying to predict. The algorithm needs to "see into the future" to know if its prediction is *correct* or not, but it does not need to know anything about the future to simply *make* the prediction.

I'm not sure you should be using individuals who have less than 6 months of follow up at all, as you don't know if they have an event within 6 months or not - I think your colleague's approach of eliminating them is reasonable. A person followed up for only 1 day likely does not have an event, but that also provides no information about whether they will in the next 6 months. You shouldn't treat that person the same as everyone else who has a full 6 month history of no event. Longer time horizons do indeed become problematic - if you want to predict if someone has an event in the next 10 years, but only have follow-up for 1 year, you have little chance of verifying your prediction.

Comment: Thanks for replying! To clarify, yes, `label` is indeed the target variable. Regarding your last paragraph, I am not talking about deleting individuals with too little data (I never mentioned “individuals”, but sure, let’s pretend it’s data about people). I am talking about removing the last 6 months across all, regardless of how much data is left for each person, because the true label value simply isn’t available. Even if we know the event did not happen last month, it might happen next month. So we don’t know what the true value for last month is (yet).

Comment: @Maya Right, that's what I meant, perhaps didn't express it well. Any consecutive trailing months with "no event" in the last 6 months of follow-up for any individual should be dropped. You don't quite need to drop the whole last 6 months for everyone - if people are followed until June, someone with no event from January-June should be dropped since we don't know if they have an event within 6m or not. But someone with an event in May should be a "1" from January-May, and only have their June data dropped as unknown.

Comment: Wouldn’t we then also have to leave at least a 6 month gap between train and test sets?